# T-SQL Distinct Close Dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005 I am selecting DATETIME from a set of two tables using a UNION. Many of these are very close together: e.g:

```
2016-01-29 10:28:57.540
2016-01-29 10:28:57.647
2016-01-29 11:23:18.193
2016-01-29 11:23:18.240
```

In this example I would like to get back just

```
2016-01-29 10:28:57.000  
2016-01-29 11:23:18.000
```

This is easy using some date/conversion functions to remove the ms part. However if we get the following:

```
2016-01-29 10:18:58.105
2016-01-29 10:18:57.952
2016-01-29 11:13:18.193
2016-01-29 11:13:18.240
```

I will get 3 datetimes when I only want 2:

```
2016-01-29 10:18:58.000
2016-01-29 10:18:57.000
2016-01-29 11:13:18.000
```

Instead of:

```
2016-01-29 10:18:58.000
2016-01-29 11:13:18.000
```

As 2016-01-29 10:18:58.105 and 2016-01-29 10:18:57.952 are less than a second apart.

So the question is how can I group together DATETIME values which are within a second of each other?

Comment: So you might groups in blocks of more than two, right?

Comment: Correct. Any times within 1000ms of each other (even if they have different second components should be grouped)

Comment: And what is there were, say, three consecutive dates with gaps of 999ms. Which group should the middle one belong with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update for MS SQL 2005**

```
DECLARE @TestDate AS TABLE (
    dt DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TestDate (dt)
VALUES 
('2016-01-29 10:18:58.105')
,('2016-01-29 10:18:57.952')
,('2016-01-29 11:13:18.193')
,('2016-01-29 11:13:18.240')


;WITH IdDt AS (
    SELECT Id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt)
            ,dt
    FROM @TestDate)

SELECt IdDt.dt
FROM IdDt
    LEFT JOIN IdDt LagDt ON IdDt.ID = LagDt.ID + 1
WHERE CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, LagDt.dt, IdDt.dt) < 1000 Then 0 ELSE 1 END = 1
```

MS SQL Server 2012 +

[MSDN Analytic function LAG()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

```
DECLARE @TestDate AS TABLE (
    dt DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TestDate (dt)
VALUES 
('2016-01-29 10:18:58.105')
,('2016-01-29 10:18:57.952')
,('2016-01-29 11:13:18.193')
,('2016-01-29 11:13:18.240')

SELECT dt
FROM (
    SELECT dt, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, LAG(dt) OVER (ORDER BY dt), dt) < 1000 Then 0 ELSE 1 END ToRemove
    FROM @TestDate
    ) Filter
WHERE ToRemove = 1;
```

Comment: Similar to my own answer. In the SQL 2005 exampe is there an advantage of using CASE WHEN?

Answer (score 1):

Decide how you want to trim microseconds and then group by the choosen function

```
select
    DT,
    -- Round down to nearest second
    DT_Floor_MS =
        dateadd(ms,-datepart(ms,a.DT),a.DT),
    -- Round up to nearest second
    DT_Ceiling_MS = 
        dateadd(ms,(1000-datepart(ms,a.DT))%1000,a.DT),
    -- Round to nearest second
    DT_Round_Off_MS =
        dateadd(ms,500-((datepart(ms,a.DT)+500)%1000),a.DT)
from
    (select --test data
        '2016-01-29 10:28:57.540' DT union all select
        '2016-01-29 10:28:57.647'union all select
        '2016-01-29 11:23:18.193'union all select
        '2016-01-29 11:23:18.240' ) a
```

```html
DT                 DT_Floor_MS                 DT_Ceiling_MS                 DT_Round_Off_MS
2016-01-29 10:28:57.540 January, 29 2016 10:28:57 January, 29 2016 10:28:58 January, 29 2016 10:28:58
2016-01-29 10:28:57.647 January, 29 2016 10:28:57 January, 29 2016 10:28:58 January, 29 2016 10:28:58
2016-01-29 11:23:18.193 January, 29 2016 11:23:18 January, 29 2016 11:23:19 January, 29 2016 11:23:18
2016-01-29 11:23:18.240 January, 29 2016 11:23:18 January, 29 2016 11:23:19 January, 29 2016 11:23:18
```

```
select 

        dateadd(ms,(1000-datepart(ms,a.DT))%1000,a.DT)
    -- Round to nearest second      
        from
    (select --test data
        '2016-01-29 10:28:57.540' DT union all select
        '2016-01-29 10:28:57.647'union all select
        '2016-01-29 11:23:18.193'union all select
        '2016-01-29 11:23:18.240' ) a

    group by

        dateadd(ms,(1000-datepart(ms,a.DT))%1000,a.DT)
    -- Round to nearest second  

2016-01-29 10:28:58.000
2016-01-29 11:23:19.000
```

Comment: This wouldn't solve the issue of having two times extremely close together but with different second components: e.g: 10:18:57.205 and 10:18:58.105 would result in two datetimes 10:18:57 and 10:18:58 and thus wouldn't be grouped despite being within a second of each other. I have found an answer to suit my needs using a join. See my answer. Thanks

Comment: @apc Oh, I missundertood your request, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for my purposes:

```
SELECT t1.UpdatedDateTime 
FROM MyTable t1 
LEFT JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.UpdatedDateTime > t2.UpdatedDateTime AND t1.UpdatedDateTime < DATEADD(SECOND,1,t2.UpdatedDateTime)
WHERE t2.UpdatedDateTime IS NULL
```

Joins the table on itself only bring back rows where the isn't another row with a time within the next second.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most direct way is to use Distinct of the datetime second approximation as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 500 - DATEPART(MILLISECOND, TimeField + '00:00:00.500'),TimeField)  FROM T1
```

Demo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b208c/3

Comment: This wouldn't solve the issue of having two times extremely close together but with different second components: e.g: 10:18:57.205 and 10:18:58.105 would result in two datetimes 10:18:57 and 10:18:58 and thus wouldn't be grouped despite being within a second of each other. I have found an answer to suit my needs using a join. See my answer. Thanks

Comment: @apc Now fixed, please try the demo
This answer now is the most optimized and simplest.